# CMS для небольшого сайта

Tags: cms

Боюсь развести холивар, но все же вот такой вопрос: нужна cms для небольшого сайта. Сайт будет чем-то похож на вот этот http://www.master-wood.com.ua/

Читал, что сейчас тройка лидеров WordPress, Joomla, Drupal.
Вот только я с пхп не знаком совершенно. И еще не особо разобрался что мне конкретно нужно. Знания html, css, sql, java, javascript, ajax есть.

Вопрос такой: какие +- у каждой, и какие ваши советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тот сайт который вы показали сделан на Joomla, и я вам тоже бы её наверно посоветовал. Наверняка все задачи с которыми вы столкнётесь можно реализовать готовыми модулями, так что знания php особо не пригодятся(но и не помешают) . Так же ничего плохого не могу сказать о Drupal или WordPress но они изначально предназначены для сайтов немного другого плана.

Comment: не подскажете, как узнали на чем сделан?

Comment: Ну это с опытом приходит, по урл, по значкам "версия для печати", "PDF". По адресу http://www.master-wood.com.ua/administrator/ админка итд

Comment: Если открыть исходный код(HTML) главной страницы того сайта, то видим следующую надпись:<br />
meta name="generator" content="Joomla! 1.5 - Open Source Content Management"

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрел пример сайта - не нашёл ничего выдающегося в функционале, поэтому любая из указанных CMS (Joomla, Drupal, WP) возможна в использовании.

Вам советую взять Joomla, сам бы я стал делать на Drupal'е(просто лично мне он намного больше знаком). Ну и вышеуказанная тройка CMS используется уже давно, поэтому с большой долей вероятности в Интернете на все возникающие вопросы уже есть написанные решения и методики.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал ImageCMS, для небольшого проекта, там php особо и не надо знать, если стандартные функции устраивают.

Comment: а какие стандартные функции?

Comment: http://www.imagecms.net/
Посмотрите страничку ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ, и всё поймёте!

Answer (score 0):

Сайт достаточно простой,вы можете реализовать его на любом движке. Думаю целесообразно было бы его сделать на http://www.santafox.ru/.
Он как раз заточен под такие задачи.

- Wodpress - под блог
- Joomla - портал
- Drupal - Мультиязычный сайт